# How to change Awesomium user agent?

Tags: vb.net, user-agent, awesomium

I have a simple form with an Awesomium webcontrol going to a website.

I found how to change the useragent in C++ but nothing for vb.net:

code for C++ http://wiki.awesomium.com/general-use/changing-the-user-agent.html

Could someone help me with this?

Comment: You could give us the link to the C++ code so we don't have to go looking for it.

Comment: So can you find the equivalent of `WebCore::Initialize` in Object Browser? If so, you need to do like in the C++ and create an object of type `WebConfig`, which is the type of the parameter to `Initialize`, set its `user_agent` field, call `WebCore.Initialize` with it and presumably `.Update` on the result of that call.

Comment: @MarkHurd im pretty green so i didnt really get what you said. I don't know how to do what you are saying.

Answer (score 1):

I realize this is an old thread and you've probably found the answer, but I added this code to my WPF VB.net app and it worked.

```
    Dim config As New Awesomium.Core.WebConfig()
    If Not Awesomium.Core.WebCore.IsInitialized Then
        Awesomium.Core.WebCore.Initialize(New Awesomium.Core.WebConfig() With { _
            .HomeURL = New Uri("https://www.awesomium.com"), _
            .RemoteDebuggingPort = 2229, _
            .UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36"
        })
    End If
```

It didn't fix the problem I was trying to fix, however it did make it so Chrome doesn't report that I'm using an old version.

Answer (score 0):

I note your answer would be [here](http://wiki.awesomium.net/winforms/webcontrol.html) if the documentation was up to date :-(

The best we can do is see what they've said for "WPF WebControl Initialization" [here](http://wiki.awesomium.net/wpf/webcontrol.html#webcore-initialization), and in summary I believe what I said in my comment holds:

- You need to use [`WebCore.Initialize(config As WebConfig)`](http://docs.awesomium.net/?tc=M_Awesomium_Core_WebCore_Initialize).

Note also the commentary [about when things occur](http://wiki.awesomium.net/general-use/initialization-sequence.html#forms-webcontrol).